# Are items discarded on use?

Tags: wizard-school

As far as I can tell the rules are very vague on if items are discarded on use.  The rules for magical friends and spells however are very clear and specifically say discarded on use.  The reason I have doubt (and this question) is because I've encountered several items (ironically?) that save items and have yet to encounter anything that makes you discard an item.

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1705755/rules-problemsclarifications does denote that in order to remove an item you have to discard it, which I can see from the rules now that I read this, but wonder if I'm just biased by this opinion.  It would at least make an application for "saving" items however.

That entire thread above just seems to be users answering other users questions, which is great but hoping for a more official source if one exists.

Comment: On discarding items: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWWHjP3pX9o) we see a Parakeet of Paralysis, which makes a player discard 2 cards; those could be Item cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items are not discarded after use.

I've found a video in which the [creator of the game explains the rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWWHjP3pX9o). Items are mentioned at 4:30. He says:

> Magical Items can be played at any time during your turn, you keep them and hold on to them, but you can only hold as many as your backpack can hold.

He then describes the backpack-property of the character he chose, Medlissa.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that video.  He actually uses "YPhone 12" in a sample attack and specifically says at 10:51 it's not discarded.  Appreciate it.